# compiling SASS on Prepros with compass - failed to compile when attempting to import compass

Tags: ruby, sass, prepros

Having completely given up attempting to touch the command line for SASS compiling, I have installed Prepos which seems to have a decent interface, and at least seems to be able to do the basics like compile SASS.

This compiles nicely when I save the file:

```
$my_color: #BADA55;

nav {
  a{
    color: $my_color;
    &:hover {
      color: darken($my_color, 10%);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem arises when I try to import compass, eg. if I add

```
@import 'compass';
```

Then I get a 'compilation failed' error- with a big red sad face, but naturally, no elaboration as to what the problem is.

To be honest, I barely know where to start to fix this. I just about grasp the basics of what I'm dealing with, but that's about it. I have found the available online documentation surrounding getting started with SASS nothing short of atrocious, which is why I have (reluctantly) turned to using a GUI. From my understanding Prepros comes with everything out of the box- including ruby and compass. So I really have no idea why this isn't working, and would greatly appreciate any pointers. Thanks.

**EDIT:** I am using the free version of Prepros (will happily pay for the full version if it actually works) and have tried adding a custom config.rb file which sets some basic configuration options:

```
relative_assets = true
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"

output_style = :expanded

line_comments = true

preferred_syntax = :scss
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, adding the config.rb file (with the above content) DOES solve the issue (I'd just made an error in the path).